How to continue to empty template when URL data is missing in Perl Dancer2
I have this route in my Dancer app: get '/newplayer/:name/:team/:season' => sub { that is called like this: https://website.com/newplayer/Joe Smith/Tigers/Fall 2024 and collects data from the url and put's into a form in the template newplayer.tt so that when the user arrives at the page this information is already mostly filled in.
It works great but I am looking for a way for the route to still be found if there are no
values supplied at the url, so that if the user goes to https://website.com/newplayer
they still arrive at the page, albeit with an empty form, instead of getting a 404 error. Does anyone know how I can do this?

You can use a forward. Using the megasplat ** instead of /:name?/:team?/:season? would make it work for partial information, too (e.g. /newplayer/Joe Smith).
get '/newplayer' => sub {
    forward '/newplayer///'
};

get '/newplayer/**' => sub {
    my @params = splat();
    my ($name, $team, $season) = @{ $params[0] };
    template('newplayer', {name => $name, team => $team, season => $season})
};

